# Reading from yaml file in xacro?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, yaml, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to read the parameters in a yaml file to my URDF using xacro. I understand that the values will be imported as a dictionary. I am able to retrieve the values when the yaml file has a single layer. For example if the yaml file is as follows:

```
val1: 0.45
val2: 0.5
```

then I can use the following commands in my xacro to get the parameters val1 and val2:

```
  <xacro:property name="yaml_file" value="$(find package)/config/paramlist.yaml" />
  <xacro:property name="dict" value="${load_yaml(yaml_file)}"/>
  <xacro:property name="val1" value="${dict['val1']}" />
  <xacro:property name="val2" value="${dict['val2']}" />
```

However I don't know how I can do the same when the yaml file has multiple 'layers' , for example:

```
Link1:
  val1: 0.45
  val2: 0.5

Link2:
  val1: 0.23
  val2: 0.33
```

I am new to ROS and to the dictionary format. How do I retrieve val1 and val2 for each Link in xacro?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396845/reading-from-yaml-file-in-xacro?/) by [ram_pk](https://answers.ros.org/users/98466/ram_pk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You will read as;

```
<xacro:property name="val1" value="${dict['Link1'][val1]}" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1